# Multiple Google Maps won't display on single page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have read many different posts about getting multiple Google maps to display on a single page, but none seem to related to my code, which uses the Google Maps API V3.

I have 2 Google Maps on the same page, but in different tabs. I have duplicated the code for Map1 and pasted it into a 2nd tab to create Map2. I have then changed the "var map" and "map_canvas" id's for Map2, but when published, only Map2 displays on the page.

I tried the option of deleting the lines;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

from the 2nd tab so that it wasn't repeated on the same page, but that didn't work.

The page can be viewed here: http://tcchurch.com.au/table1/index.php/missions

The 2 different maps are supposed to display under the tabs "Our Missionaries" and "International Partners".

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Ian

Comment: Check the javascript console.  I get this warning: `Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. main.js:42` and this error `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://tcchurch.com.au/table1/index.php/missions from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/32423470?portrait=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: [3 maps on one page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polygon-simple_3maps.html)

Comment: I have removed the repeated API and also the vimeo video from the code, but still only one map displays.

Comment: I see a map in the tab "International Partners"; where is the other map supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

You have duplicate functions.  That won't work, give them unique names as well, or have one initialize function that initializes both maps.

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 40);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}, 
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
....
}

function initialize2() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 40);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}, 
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), settings);
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me. When I changed Map2's function to: function initialize2(), the map fails to display. Is that the correct way to give it a unique name?

Comment: Yes, that should work (assuming you call the function).  Your HTML is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftcchurch.com.au%2Ftable1%2Findex.php%2Fmissions&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  You have multiple head and body tags.  That won't work either. None of this has anything to do with Google Maps or the Google Maps API, it is all general HTML/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not only give different names to functions but also to global variables - variables without "var" at the begging:

Assigning post id to: "map", "initialize" and "codeAddress" like this (not super clean but works):

```
var geocoder;
    var map;

    function codeAddress<? echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>() {
      var address = "<? echo h($post['Post']['address']); ?>, <? echo h($post['Post']['ZIP']); ?> <? echo $cities[$post['Post']['city_id']]; ?>";
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map<? echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map<? echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

    function initialize<? echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latlng
      }
      map<? echo $post['Post']['id']; ?> = new google.maps.Map($('googleMap<? echo $post["Post"]["id"]; ?>'), mapOptions);
      codeAddress<? echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>()
    }   

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize<? echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>);
```