# Displaying Multiple Google Maps on one page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a bit of trouble which should be easy but I am missing something but not sure what. I have the code in two separate js files then call them in the head.

These are the two maps.

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/aqiCurrent.js

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/aqiForecast.js

Then I would add this in the head section. This works great for single maps on one page but not two.

```
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmOjwJpRcp48pn7smsrprlnN90iYBxR8g&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gmap/aqiCurrent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gmap/aqiForecast.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
```

Then I call the maps in the html like so.

```
<div id="aqiCurrent" style="width:100%; height:400px"> </div>

<div id="aqiForecast" style="width:100%; height:400px"> </div>
```

It only displays the second map not the first one. If I remove one of the calls from the head then the first one shows. So I know the code is good because I can get one or the other to load and display. I just can't get them both to load and display at the same time. I am not sure what I am missing.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Multiple Google Maps won't display on single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578425/multiple-google-maps-wont-display-on-single-page/16579089#16579089)

You have a function with the same name in both the javascript files ("initialize").

That won't work.

Comment: I have tired renaming them function initialize1() and function initialize2() and then they don't load at all. I have even tried removing it all together and just having it load from <body onload="initialize()">. Even tried removing it. Nothing I have tried works. It loads the second map but not the first map. You would think in theory if there is a naming conflict it would load the first but not the second.

Comment: I got it sorted. I just combined the two codes and called it with on function. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/aqiLocal.js